# Unresolved dependency on sbt-android 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT with sbt 0.13 and Scala 2.10?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I'm developing a Hello World-like Android application in Scala.

I have followed [the Getting Started tutorial](http://fxthomas.github.io/android-plugin/tutorial/01-getting-started.html) in the SBT-Android documentation and also tried applying the recommendations from the [Scala on Android](https://leanpub.com/ScalaOnAndroid) book. One does everything from scratch the other does `g8 Geal/android-app`.

In both cases however I'm facing the same error:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt-android;0.7.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jcarres/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-android_2.10_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-android-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== scalasbt releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#sbt-android;0.7.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I've tried several versions of `sbt-android` and it seems that the problem is that my Scala and sbt versions do not match.

When I visit http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-android I can only see the `scala_2.9.2` directory while my version of Scala is `2.10`. My version of sbt is `0.13` while it seems it should be `0.12`.

Do I need to delete Scala `2.10` and install Scala `2.9.2` and/or downgrade sbt to `0.12`? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sbt` uses a copy of Scala that it downloads itself - it will automatically download the "right" version - so there is no need to mess around with your own installed copy of Scala.

Because this is a `sbt` plugin you will need to change the `sbt` version to the one it expects, in `project/build.properties` (if this file does not exist, you can just create it, with the following contents):

```
sbt.version=0.12.0
```

Make sure you `reload` sbt, so that the new (old) version of sbt gets loaded.

Alternatively, of course, you could try to compile `sbt-android-plugin` from source for sbt `0.13`, by doing the opposite manoeuvre (you might need to build and `publish-local` some of its dependencies). It might work.